# Python : sklearn svm, providing a custom loss function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

The way I use sklearn's svm module now, is to use its defaults. However, its not doing particularly well for my dataset. Is it possible to provide a custom loss function , or a custom kernel? If so, what is the way to write such a function so that it matches with what sklearn's svm expects and how to pass such a function to the trainer?

There is this example of how to do it:
[SVM custom kernel](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html)

code cited here:

```
def my_kernel(x, y):
"""
We create a custom kernel:

             (2  0)
k(x, y) = x  (    ) y.T
             (0  1)
"""
M = np.array([[2, 0], [0, 1.0]])
return np.dot(np.dot(x, M), y.T)
```

I'd like to understand the logic behind this kernel. How to choose the kernel matrix? And what exactly is `y.T` ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, unless you have a very good idea of *why* you want to define a custom kernel, I'd stick with the built-ins. They are very fast, flexible, and powerful, and are well-suited to most applications.

That being said, let's go into a bit more detail:

A [Kernel Function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-kernels) is a special kind of measure of similarity between two points. Basically a larger value of the similarity means the points are more similar. The scikit-learn SVM is designed to be able to work with any kernel function. Several kernels built-in (e.g. linear, radial basis function, polynomial, sigmoid) but you can also define your own.

Your custom kernel function should look something like this:

```
def my_kernel(x, y):
    """Compute My Kernel

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array, shape=(N, D)
    y : array, shape=(M, D)
        input vectors for kernel similarity

    Returns
    -------
    K : array, shape=(N, M)
        matrix of similarities between x and y
    """
    # ... compute something here ...
    return similarity_matrix
```

The most basic kernel, a linear kernel, would look like this:

```
def linear_kernel(x, y):
    return np.dot(x, y.T)
```

Equivalently, you can write

```
def linear_kernel_2(x, y):
    M = np.array([[1, 0],
                  [0, 1]])
    return np.dot(x, np.dot(M, y.T))
```

The matrix `M` here defines the so-called [inner product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) in which the kernel acts. This matrix can be modified to define a new inner product space; the custom function from the example you linked to just modifies `M` to effectively double the importance of the first dimension in determining the similarity.

More complicated non-linear modifications are possible as well, but you have to be careful: kernel functions must meet [certain requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method#Mathematics) (they must satisfy the properties of an inner-product space) or the SVM algorithm will not work correctly.